# Dapper - two columns to be switched over time (controlled by config value)

Tags: dapper

I have the following problem:
A several tables with "data", "token_data" columns that switch their values over time

Phases:

1. In the current phase 0, there is only "data" column (clear data).
2. In phase 1 there will be "data", "token_data" columns.
3. In the phase 2, there will be "token_data", "clear_data" columns.
4. In the last phase 3, there should be only "data" column (by that
   time it should be tokenized).

We currently have all dapper/db models with phase 0 in mind.

Is there a way to prepare Dapper models for all 4 phases? I was looking for OptionalColumn attribute, but couldn't find one.
Ideally there would be a global config switch that would control which Dapper model property represents the tokenized "data" column.
Like:

```
// Not good
    [Column("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return AppSettings.TokenizationEnabled ? this.TokenName : _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you need to do. For example, why you can'y just created a class with all properties, and, depending on the phase, return the correct data for that phase. Something like:

```
class MyData {
    public int Phase;
    public String Data { private get; public set; }
    public String Token_Data { private get; public set; }
    public String Clean_Data { private get; public set; }
    public String GetData() 
    { 
        switch(Phase): {
        case 1: return Token_Data; break;
        case 2: return Clean_data; break;
        default: return Data; break
    }
}
```

Aside from that, anyway, I think the feature called "Type Switching per Row" can help you: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#type-switching-per-row

Comment: The problem is, we've got [Column] attributes all over the place, so Dapper to SQL column mappings are already set. And if we implement new fields with new Column attributes, then we're busted in phase 4.